# Is there a way to simplify the code in VBA in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**(1*8)+(2*8)+(3*8)+(4*8)+(5*8)** be written as **(1+2+3+4+5)*8**.

How can I simplify the code below in a similar way?

```vba
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Label1.BackColor = &H8000000F
Label2.BackColor = &H8000000F
Label3.BackColor = &H8000000F
Label4.BackColor = &H8000000F
Label5.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

Actually I have heard of a solution that uses `With`, but so far I never get to see them applied in PowerPoint.

Comment: That code is as simple as it gets.  I presume you are saying that you don't want to write the same thing multiple times, but sometimes (especially with userforms) you just have to.

Comment: With blocks, fyi would be if you were doing multiple different things to one object, not the same thing to multiple objects

Comment: there is potentially a way to use a loop with string concatnation but I'm not sure how you'd have VBA interpret the string result as a command to be executed

Answer (score 2):

you can't use `With` keyword for such a task

but you can do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        Me.Controls("Label" & i).BackColor = &H8000000F
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried and I was told "Method or data member not found. " and `.Controls` was highlighted. Could you make further explanations about how this should work or why couldn't I make mine work with this code?

Comment: I assume a Userform with a `Button` control named after "CommandButton1" and many `Label` controls named after "Label1", "Label2" ,.... In the Userform code pane there's the "CommandButton1" button `Click` event handler, thus named after `CommandButton1_Click()`, that gets executed upon the user clicking that button. There, the `Me` keyword points at the Userform object whose `.Controls` property returns the collection of all Userform controls each to be picked via its name (like "Label1") and be set via its properties (like `BackColor ` one)

Comment: @chin98edwin : did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a range for the labels and call it by range as opposed to label.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
rangeName = &H8000000F
End Sub

Comment: Can you suggest a bit of example code that demonstrates how to create a range of labels?